# To which url should the Telegram APIs send data?

Tags: api, telegram

Hi in telegram api i found this api [auth.checkPhone](https://core.telegram.org/method/auth.checkPhone) but telegram only show data to send and receive, no url to send that data how can i use those api? To which telegram url should i send data (not bot api here)